# Dataframe splitting in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, split

i Have a dataframe DF ,  and column name DETAILS,  i want the value which are in double quotes (""), will make new column VALUE

DF=

```
      DETAILS                      
   Username as "JOHN"           
   verifying the name             
   click UserBox                  
   Password as "345678"          
   Click login                   
   click checkbox                 
   Phonenumber as "34512345"     
   Checking data
```

I want my data frame look like this

DF=

```
     DETAILS                      VALUE
   Username as "JOHN"           "JOHN"
   verifying the name             NA
   click UserBox                  NA
   Password as "345678"          "3345678"
   Click login                    NA
   click checkbox                 NA
   Phonenumber as "34512345"     "34512345"
   Checking data                 NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `str` accessor has an `extract` method for that kind of use case:

```
DF['VALUE'] = DF['DETAILS'].str.extract('(".*?")')
```

With your data, it gives as expected:

```
                     DETAILS       VALUE
0         Username as "JOHN"      "JOHN"
1         verifying the name         NaN
2              click UserBox         NaN
3       Password as "345678"    "345678"
4                Click login         NaN
5             click checkbox         NaN
6  Phonenumber as "34512345"  "34512345"
7              Checking data         NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
df['VALUE'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: '"' + x['DETAILS'].split('"')[1] + '"' 
                if len(x['DETAILS'].split('"')) > 1 
                else 'NA',
    1)
```

This will output:

```
                     DETAILS       VALUE
0         Username as "JOHN"      "JOHN"
1         verifying the name          NA
2              click UserBox          NA
3       Password as "345678"    "345678"
4                Click login          NA
5             click checkbox          NA
6  Phonenumber as "34512345"  "34512345"
7              Checking data          NA
```

with the column *VALUES* containing your values where present, else *NA*.